# PhpStorm: cannot get autocomple to work in .eex files

Tags: elixir, phpstorm, webstorm, code-completion

I'm using Elixir and I've set it up with PhpStorm, its working fantastically. However I cannot seem to get autocompletion to work inside `.eex` files.

For example, when I do this:

[image]

and click <kbd>Tab</kbd> I expect to get the snippet `<h1></h1>` but instead I get nothing. Any clues would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: 1) What plugin do you use for that? 2) How does plain / valid HTML looks there (whole editor tab)? **P.S.** The feature you are after `h1` into `<h1></h1>` called Emmet. Maybe it does not work in such file for whatever reason (I'm not familiar with Elixir so do not know what I can write there to see how it all works in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

In **Settings | Editor | Live Templates | Zen HTML**, select any template, in scope chooser tick **Other**:

[image]

this should enable basic Emmet completion in all 'unknown' file types, including Elixir